# How to route dynamic content?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm front end designer and trying to figure out how to use VueJS.

My github: https://github.com/soraname/mangarou

Here is my problem:

> User click Soraname page
> Route to Soraname page - (soraname.vue)
> Load component Autor.vue - send prop or parameter
> Load Soraname content

Basically, Page A route to Page A View, load Component with Page A content.
Valid if click Page B, C, D. Everyone use the same Component but change the content data.

I don't know how to do it, pass a variable to set what Data should load.

I've tried this:

## soraname.vue (View)

```
<template>
  <div class="soraname content-box">
    <Autor v-bind="soraname"></Autor>
  </div>
</template>
```

## Load the Component Autor.vue

```
<template>
<div id="Autor">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 autor-header">
        <img :src="pageautor.Logo" width="128"> <h1>{{pageautor.Nome}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 autor-header">
      <h3>Bio</h3>
      <p>{{pageautor.Bio}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
      name: 'autor',
      components: {
      },
      data() {
        return {
            pageautor: {
              Nome: "Soraname3333", 
              Bio: '/soraname', 
              Logo: '/assets/media/logos/soraname.png',  
              Color: 'purple accent-3',
              links: [
                {
                  Item: 'LINKSoraname', 
                  Elo: '/soraname', 
                  Text: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ', 
                  Img: '/autores/soraname/link01.png'
                }
              ],
              mangas: [
                {
                  Titulo: 'MANGASoraname', 
                  Elo: '/soraname', 
                  Sinopse: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ',
                  Img: '/assets/media/logos/soraname.png'
                }
              ]
            },
            soraname: {
              Nome: "SoranamDDDe", 
              Bio: '/soraname', 
              Logo: '/assets/media/logos/soraname.png',  
              Color: 'purple accent-3',
              links: [
                {
                  Item: 'LINKSoraname', 
                  Elo: '/soraname', 
                  Text: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ', 
                  Img: '/autores/soraname/link01.png'
                }
              ],
              mangas: [
                {
                  Titulo: 'MANGASoraname', 
                  Elo: '/soraname', 
                  Sinopse: 'lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ',
                  Img: '/assets/media/logos/soraname.png'
                }
              ]
            }
          }
      },
      methods: {
      }
    };
</script>
```

Router: https://github.com/soraname/mangarou/blob/master/src/router.js
Soraname View (Page A): https://github.com/soraname/mangarou/blob/master/src/views/soraname.vue
Autor.vue (Component): https://github.com/soraname/mangarou/blob/master/src/components/Autores/Autor.vue

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the data comes from a remote server, you can use your component to make an AJAX call and store the result however a better approach will be to use [VUEX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) as a centralized state - with this approach you will also be able to use the author data across multiple components without the need to pass it over and over.

To make it clear, your route should have a parameter to identify the selected author (surname, id, whatever) - you do that with `:surname` when specifying the route. Then your component is loaded and read the parameter from the route `this.$route.params.surname` then use it to load the data from a remote server / vuex

Comment: Thnx! I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't need vuex you need a parent component (maybe layout) that gets the data has a computed property which it passes to the child component, the computed property is the data you want, it will update when your child component emits a change that triggers an event to change one of it's dependencies.
So basically parent handles data passes down to child and changes based on events emitted from child.